# Vercel / Sanity deployment issue

Tags: reactjs, vercel, sanity

Hey guys im trying to deploy my project.
I run Vercel Build through my terminal it comes back with no errors but when run vercel deploy I keep getting
`Build Failed Command "npm run build" exited with 1`

Any suggestions or fixes would be greatly apreciated!
I see it says I need a projectId but my .env.local contains my id

`````
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET=production
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID=8a64h111
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/````
 
I'm really stumped here.

```23:27:55.917 | Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`
23:27:55.917 | at exports.initConfig (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@sanity/client/lib/config.js:42:11)
23:27:55.918 | at SanityClient.config (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@sanity/client/lib/sanityClient.js:89:25)
23:27:55.918 | at new SanityClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@sanity/client/lib/sanityClient.js:53:8)
23:27:55.918 | at SanityClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/@sanity/client/lib/sanityClient.js:50:12)
23:27:55.918 | at exports.createClient (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next-sanity/dist/next-sanity.cjs.production.min.js:1:1023)
23:27:55.918 | at Object.5149 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:1055:75)
23:27:55.919 | at __webpack_require__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
23:27:55.919 | at /vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:20:65
23:27:55.919 | at Function.__webpack_require__.a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:89:13)
23:27:55.919 | at Object.2265 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/index.js:11:21)
23:27:55.920 |  
23:27:55.920 | > Build error occurred
23:27:55.922 | Error: Failed to collect page data for /
23:27:55.922 | at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:916:15 {
23:27:55.922 | type: 'Error'
23:27:55.923 | }
23:27:55.978 | Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1```
`````

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```23:27:55.917 | Error: Configuration must contain `projectId`

It looks like you didn't add the environment variable "projectId" on Varcel. [Here's how to do it.](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables). If you added it, check if you have a typo there.

Comment: This fixed the project id issue thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information in addition to the stack trace but assuming all libraries are working correctly...

Most libraries don't read from `.env.local` or `process.env` by default. You first use *another* library like dotenv-flow to load `.env.local` into `process.env`, then pass a configuration (usually an object) to the library's constructor.

Line 20, column 65 of `pages/index.js` (assuming you are not compiling from typescript) may look something like this: `createClient()` you want it to look like this: `createClient({projectId: process.env.projectId})`

Comment: *`Libraries don't read from .env.local or process.env by default.`* Some libraries/frameworks do read environment variables from those files.

Comment: @vighnesh153 Yes i've caught that and changed it (before you made the comment), but that detail should have very little consequence here. next-sanity is not a framework and does not read from process.env. Other similar libraries do the same.